# EntitySubqueue save() only working with die() following it

Tags: 8, queue

I am trying to add an item to a sub-queue automatically on save. And for some reason, it only works if I include `die()` afterwards.

#### This adds the new node to the queue

```php
function custom_module_entity_insert(EntityInterface $entity) {
  ...
  $subqueue = EntitySubqueue::load($entityqueue_id);
  $subqueue->addItem($entity)->save();
  die();
}
```

#### This does NOT add the new node to the queue

```php
function custom_module_entity_insert(EntityInterface $entity) {
  ...
  $subqueue = EntitySubqueue::load($entityqueue_id);
  $subqueue->addItem($entity)->save();
}
```

I've tried putting sleep statements around and can't get it to work without `die()`, which breaks the page after saving, obviously. There aren't any helpful messages in the error log. The item saves, it just doesn't get added to the queue without `die()`.

Do you have any idea?

#### This is my working function (and breaks the page)

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_insert().
 */
function custom_module_entity_insert(EntityInterface $entity) {
  // Only worry about entities that are fieldable.
  if ($entity instanceof FieldableEntityInterface) {
    if ($entity instanceof NodeInterface &&
        in_array($entity->getType(), ['podcast','video','post'])) {
      automaticallyAddToEntityqueue($entity);
    }
  }
}

function automaticallyAddToEntityqueue(EntityInterface $entity) {
  $entity_queue_type_mapping = array(
    'podcast' => 'everything_else_podcast',
    'video' => 'everything_else_video',
    'post' => 'everything_else_post'
  );
  foreach ($entity_queue_type_mapping as $type => $entityqueue_id) {
    if ($entity instanceof NodeInterface && $type == $entity->getType()) {
      /** @var \Drupal\entityqueue\EntitySubqueueInterface $subqueue */
      $subqueue = EntitySubqueue::load($entityqueue_id);
      if (method_exists($subqueue, 'addItem')) {
        $subqueue->addItem($entity)->save();
        die();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That mean, you have a loop process. Let check more condition to stop your loop process.

Comment: Does it re-save the entity after adding it to the subqueue? Like does it save a reference to the queue on the entity, too? Although updates to nodes shouldn't trigger hook_entity_insert again... This bug has been taking me a lot of time to figure out.

Comment: Update: added my full function.

Comment: Let check variable $entity_queue_type_mapping, try with only item 'podcast' => 'everything_else_podcast' and remove line die().

Comment: MrD nope... not working either.

Comment: Did you check if there are other modules installed which implement `hook_entity_insert` (or similar hooks), that might interfere? As `die()` simply interrupts code execution, it's not limited to your current function, but also prevents any code after your hook invocation from running, so I'd look there.